# EXTJS propertyGrid key column checkbox

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

Is there any way to put a checkbox to any row first column in property.Grid like in the picture?

[image]

Comment: not as simple as you want. it's not a config issue but more as js playing around and adding it to the cell